# Which kind of sampling is it?

Tags: sampling, sample

What kind of sampling it would be if I leave a notice on the board of some university departments to test individuals who call me?

Comment: Various writers about sampling methods have different lists of methods. Your sampling method is not 'random' ('simple' or 'stratified'), some would call it a 'convenience' sample or a sample of 'volunteers'. // I have put single quotes around often-used type names. // If this is for a course, it would help if you give a list from which you are expected to choose.

Answer (score 2):

Posting a phone number on a board in select departments at a unversity asking for volunteers would likely result in candidates who are healthy, above average in intellect, motivation, character and as such, perhaps representative of future above average wage earners, homeowners, etc., and depending on the international student population present at the university, the volunteers may not be even representative of the local suggested cutout.

As such, it appears that this recruiting results in so-called [Convenience Sampling](https://www.statisticshowto.com/convenience-sampling/). Typical comments on the disadvantages of convenience sampling include, to quote:

> - An inability to generalize the results of the survey to the population as a whole.
> - The possibility of under- or over-representation of the population.
> - Biased results, due to the reasons why some people choose to take part and some do not.

Comment: I see but in my department, almost all people, even our professors do that. I study neuroscience. And I think maybe as the function of our brain or in my case (perception of musical features) is likely to be less affected by people’s characters or moods or so on, this method is agreeable. Is it right?

Comment: No. I can imagine other reasons for non-participation, including lack of time, which in itself may have diverse causes.